# Con Regex, ¿cómo obtengo lo que está entre paréntesis que tenga una determinada cadena de texto?

Tags: regex

Estoy usando Regex para renombrar archivos en Total Commander y necesito eliminar una parte que está entre paréntesis.

Por ejemplo, dadas las siguientes cadenas y siendo el texto a buscar `con`:

> Texto adelante (texto con paréntesis)
>
> Dice algo (con otra cosa) y algo más
>
> De nuevo (no coincide) y (ahora con esto si) va
>
> Ultimo (texto con) dato (también con) con nada

Debería devolver lo siguiente:
`(texto con paréntesis)`
`(con otra cosa)`
`(ahora con esto si)`
`(texto con)` y `(también con)`

Jugando un poco en [regexr](http://regexr.com/3gb9h): `\\((.*?)\\)` que obviamente también toma `(no coincide)` y no debería.

`\\(((con).*?)\\)` sólo toma `(con otra cosa)`

`\\((.*?(con).*?)\\)` también toma `(no coincide)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo único que tendrías que cambiar sería el `.*` para que no te incluya los paréntesis de otro match. Espero te sirva.

```
\(([^()]*con[^()]*)\)
```

`[^()]*` Todos los caracteres excepto `'('` y '`)'`

Puedes comprobarlo [Aquí](https://regex101.com/r/nACKxp/2)